# create pdf using byte stream in android

Tags: android, pdf

i have byte stream and  create pdf using byte stream. i  try this code.

```
        byte[] bytes;
        File createfile = new File("/sdcard/Androidrox/");
        createfile.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(createfile, "Sample.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);
        doc.open();
        String strByte = editText.getText().toString();       
        bytes=strByte.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        String filepath = "/sdcard/Androidrox/Sample.pdf";
        OutputStream pdffos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
        pdffos.write(bytes);
        pdffos.flush();
        pdffos.close();
```

I cannot open the file. "ERROR, There was an error opening the document. please help me to identify the error

Comment: Logcat output please

Answer (score 0):

try this to create PDF file

```
File FILE;
PdfWriter pdfWriter;
FILE = createDirectory(path, projectListBean.getProjectName() + ".pdf");
Document document = new Document();
pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

public File createDirectory(String path, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File directory = new File(path);
    directory.mkdirs();
    return new File(directory, filename);
}
```